# Writing function to replace for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

My for loop code iterates over each row and multiplies each predictor variable value by a coefficient value:

```
lpb1B$HKGLMM <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(lpb1B)) { 
lpb1B$HKGLMM[i] <- 
(exp(-93.7016 + (2.76336 * lpb1B$Depth[i]) 
+ (-0.02  * (lpb1B$Depth[i] * lpb1B$Depth[i])) 
+ (-0.00003 * lpb1B$Dist[i]) 
+ (-0.0059 * lpb1B$Aspect[i]))) / (1 + exp(-93.7016 + (2.76336 * lpb1B$Depth[i]) 
+ (-0.02  * (lpb1B$Depth[i] * lpb1B$Depth[i])) 
+ (-0.00003 * lpb1B$Dist[i]) 
+ (-0.0059 * lpb1B$Aspect[i])))
}
```

Now that's some messy, lengthy code. I haven't found an example using apply() that helps me avoid this loop. Is there any way to circumvent this monster loop?

Comment: So given that the constants don't change for each `i`, you can remove the `for` loop and just run what's inside it (without the `[i]` parts. So, it will look like `lpb1B$HKGLMM<- (exp(-93.7016 + (2.76336 * lpb1B$Depth) + ... +  (-0.0059 * lpb1B$Aspect)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this much more compactly (if you like) by recasting it as a problem where you multiply a model matrix (i.e., a matrix with your data as columns) by a coefficient vector.  The only potentially tricky part is matching up the order of the coefficients and the columns of the model matrix ...

Using @Phil's example:

```
lpb1B <- data.frame(
   Depth = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
   Dist  = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
   Aspect = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE)
 )
 X <- model.matrix(~Dist+Aspect+Depth+I(Depth^2),lpb1B)
```

Check the order of columns:

```
 colnames(X)
 ## [1] "(Intercept)" "Dist"        "Aspect"      "Depth"       "I(Depth^2)"
```

Construct a matching parameter vector:

```
 beta <- c(-93.7016,-0.00003,-0.0059,2.76336,-0.02)
```

Then (using `plogis(x)` instead of `exp(x)/(1+exp(x))` this encapsulates your loop:

```
 lpb1B$HKGLMM <- plogis(X %*% beta)
```

Comment: This works beautifully- I'm honored (and well-served) that you took the time to construct this sleek, simple example for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly along the lines of @yannis 's answer:

```
lpb1B <- data.frame(
  Depth = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
  Dist  = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
  Aspect = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
lpb1B$HKGLMM <- NA

lpb1B$HKGLMM <- 
  (exp(-93.7016 + (2.76336 * lpb1B$Depth) + 
         (-0.02  * (lpb1B$Depth * lpb1B$Depth)) +
         (-0.00003 * lpb1B$Dist) + 
         (-0.0059 * lpb1B$Aspect))) / 
  (1 + exp(-93.7016 + (2.76336 * lpb1B$Depth) + 
             (-0.02  * (lpb1B$Depth * lpb1B$Depth)) + 
             (-0.00003 * lpb1B$Dist) + 
             (-0.0059 * lpb1B$Aspect)))
```

Comment: This works as well- bravo, thank you. Down with the unnecessarily cumbersome for loop!